# Module not found error when running script as wsgi within Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wps

I have a developed Server application using pywps on a Flask server and now im trying to migrate it to an apache server.

Tech-stack :
OS: Windows Server
Python 3.9.6
Apache 2.4.48 (Win64)
mod-wsgi        4.8.0

I can open the configured URL but receive a status code 500. Error log says the following:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=7212, process='', application='127.0.0.1:8008|/wps'): Loading Python script file 'C:/Apache24/wps_env/pywps-flask-master/pywps.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=7212): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/Apache24/wps_env/pywps-flask-master/pywps.wsgi'.
mod_wsgi (pid=7212): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/Apache24/wps_env/pywps-flask-master/pywps.wsgi'.
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
File "C:/Apache24/wps_env/pywps-flask-master/pywps.wsgi", line 9, in <module>\r
 import pywps\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywps'\r
```

The wsgi file in question is :

```
from pathlib import Path
import pywps
from pywps import Service

from processes.sayhello import SayHello
from processes.csv_input import CSVInputs 

processes = [
    SayHello(),
    CSVInputs()
]
application = Service(processes, [Path(r'C:\Users\Jdoe\wps_env\pywps-flask-master\pywps.cfg')])
```

Now comes the strange thing, i am able to execute this exakt same script from the powershell with no errors at all.
I would rule out, path or enviroment related issues, because i have installed all pip packages which i used in the virtaul enviroemnt i have to develop in the global namespace aswell, so both interpreters know the same packages. I know this is not best practice, but i'm currently working in a sandbox anyway and this more a POC then anything else.

Since the wsgi application tries to run, i also assume that my apache conf is correct.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

`ModuleNotFoundError` means that a module is missing and that you have to install it. In your case its PyWPS.
So open a terminal and type

```
pip install pywps
```

or

```
pip3 install pywps
```

then if you rerun your code it should work.

P.S. You can find the package on [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pywps/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the module is already installed. I will add a screenshot of the pip list as soon as i can